# Python comparing strings, problem with endlines

Tags: python, string, for-loop, oop, substring

Hi guys I have two different strings. One of these  stings is a description and the other one is a template.

I want to check if the template is inclued in the description.

The Problem is that I cant just do

```
if template in description:
   print("template is included")
   return True
else: raise Exception("exception test23")
```

Comment: Use a regular expression to represent the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert your whole template into a regular expression, you will need to escape it using re.escape.  Within that expression, you will want some parts to be treated as wildcards so that content may vary in the document (i.e. "X" between brackets).  You can alter the escaped pattern to replace placeholders with expressions that will account for the variations:

Between your template and the actual content, there is also a few spaces on empty lines that create an invisible difference.  This may just be a copy/paste issue but in case it is a legitimate difference, I made an additional alteration to the template pattern to ignore extra spaces at the beginning of each line.

```
import re
pattern = template.replace("[ ]","[CHECK]") # allow variable content between []
pattern = re.escape(pattern).replace("CHECK",r".+") # CHECK-->regular exp.
pattern = pattern.replace("\n","\n *") # for extra spaces at begining of lines

if re.search(pattern,document):
    print("contains template")
else:
    print("does not contain template")
```

output:

```
template="""<details>

<summary> <b>Technical Template</b>
</summary>

- [ ] Formal

##### Formal
- Is the document template used properly and consistently?
- Has the generated pdf file been checked?

##### Content
- Is the user documentation clear, correct and complete?

</details>"""

document = """| customer-check  |/ | 
 | --- | --- | 

<details>

<summary> <b> Completeness</b>
</summary>

- [x] Formal

</details>


<details>

<summary> <b>Technical Template</b>
</summary>

- [x] Formal
- [x] Content

##### Formal
- Is the document template used properly and consistently?
- Has the generated pdf file been checked?
 
</details>"""

# this prints: contains template
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your question, I dont get any error so it finds the template in my document. What I dont understand: The Part with WILDCARD. I tried it without and used your .replace(r"\[\ ]\",r"\[.+\]") but I get a syntax error @alain

Comment: E       pattern = re.escape(pattern).replace.(r"\[\ ]\",r"\[.+\]")
E                                            ^
E   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: There was a misplaced backslash. Fixed it now

Comment: The WILDCARD part is to have something that won't be escaped between the bracket so that replacing it with ".+" is easier after re.escape() adds a bunch of special characters.   Escaping `[WILDCARD]` produces `\[WILDCARD\]` but escaping `[ ]` produces `\[\ \]`.  Using the WILDCARD keyword, you won't need to know how re.escape does its job.

Comment: tried x = document.replace("- [x]", "- [ ]") so it should be almost the same I think but I still get an error and still trying it